# can't start Mariadb after successful installtion

Tags: centos6, installation, mariadb

I am using CentOS 6.8, and want to install mariadb 5.5. 
I followed all steps in https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/yum/

```
vi /etc/yum.repos.d/MariaDB.repo
```

then inserting

```
# MariaDB 5.5 CentOS repository list - created 2017-01-05 04:37 UTC
# http://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/
[mariadb]
name = MariaDB
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/5.5/centos6-amd64
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck=1
```

then running

```
sudo yum install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client
```

the installation when successfully, after that I want to start the database

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

unfortunately this error is coming on:

```
Starting MySQL.170105 08:42:42 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/lib/mysql/test.mcc.edu.om.err'.
170105 08:42:42 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe_helper: Can't create/write to file '' (Errcode: -328342880)
 ERROR!
```

there is no logs in /var/log/

can someone guide me what might be the problem???

I tried also to chown -R mysql:mysql to all dir relted to mysql in /var/lib or /usr/lib or /usr/share with no success,

any advice please ??

as requested by [@Koen van der Rijt](https://serverfault.com/users/200850/koen-van-der-rijt)

here is the output of /var/log/audit/audit.log after running the /etc/init.d/mysql start

```
type=USER_CMD msg=audit(1483602976.169:249): user pid=9358 uid=0 auid=0 ses=2 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='cwd="/" cmd=2F6574632F696E69742E642F6D7973716C207374617274 terminal=pts/0 res=success'
type=CRED_ACQ msg=audit(1483602976.169:250): user pid=9358 uid=0 auid=0 ses=2 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:setcred acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'
type=USER_START msg=audit(1483602976.169:251): user pid=9358 uid=0 auid=0 ses=2 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:session_open acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'
type=AVC msg=audit(1483602976.350:252): avc:  denied  { setgid } for  pid=9450 comm="mysqld_safe_hel" capability=6  scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:mysqld_safe_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:system_r:mysqld_safe_t:s0 tclass=capability
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1483602976.350:252): arch=c000003e syscall=116 success=no exit=-1 a0=1 a1=11de600 a2=10000 a3=1 items=0 ppid=9365 pid=9450 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts0 ses=2 comm="mysqld_safe_hel" exe="/usr/bin/mysqld_safe_helper" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:mysqld_safe_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1483602976.350:253): avc:  denied  { setgid } for  pid=9450 comm="mysqld_safe_hel" capability=6  scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:mysqld_safe_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:system_r:mysqld_safe_t:s0 tclass=capability
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1483602976.350:253): arch=c000003e syscall=106 success=no exit=-1 a0=1f3 a1=1f3 a2=ca a3=7ffef20f7170 items=0 ppid=9365 pid=9450 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts0 ses=2 comm="mysqld_safe_hel" exe="/usr/bin/mysqld_safe_helper" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:mysqld_safe_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1483602976.371:254): avc:  denied  { setgid } for  pid=9461 comm="mysqld_safe_hel" capability=6  scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:mysqld_safe_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:system_r:mysqld_safe_t:s0 tclass=capability
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1483602976.371:254): arch=c000003e syscall=116 success=no exit=-1 a0=1 a1=2818600 a2=10000 a3=1 items=0 ppid=9365 pid=9461 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts0 ses=2 comm="mysqld_safe_hel" exe="/usr/bin/mysqld_safe_helper" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:mysqld_safe_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1483602976.372:255): avc:  denied  { setgid } for  pid=9461 comm="mysqld_safe_hel" capability=6  scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:mysqld_safe_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:system_r:mysqld_safe_t:s0 tclass=capability
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1483602976.372:255): arch=c000003e syscall=106 success=no exit=-1 a0=1f3 a1=1f3 a2=ca a3=7ffeeb737ad0 items=0 ppid=9365 pid=9461 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts0 ses=2 comm="mysqld_safe_hel" exe="/usr/bin/mysqld_safe_helper" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:mysqld_safe_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1483602976.394:256): avc:  denied  { setgid } for  pid=9467 comm="mysqld_safe_hel" capability=6  scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:mysqld_safe_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:system_r:mysqld_safe_t:s0 tclass=capability
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1483602976.394:256): arch=c000003e syscall=116 success=no exit=-1 a0=1 a1=ee0600 a2=10000 a3=1 items=0 ppid=9365 pid=9467 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts0 ses=2 comm="mysqld_safe_hel" exe="/usr/bin/mysqld_safe_helper" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:mysqld_safe_t:s0 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1483602976.394:257): avc:  denied  { setgid } for  pid=9467 comm="mysqld_safe_hel" capability=6  scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:mysqld_safe_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:system_r:mysqld_safe_t:s0 tclass=capability
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1483602976.394:257): arch=c000003e syscall=106 success=no exit=-1 a0=1f3 a1=1f3 a2=ca a3=7ffc7f986aa0 items=0 ppid=9365 pid=9467 auid=0 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts0 ses=2 comm="mysqld_safe_hel" exe="/usr/bin/mysqld_safe_helper" subj=unconfined_u:system_r:mysqld_safe_t:s0 key=(null)
type=USER_END msg=audit(1483602977.229:258): user pid=9358 uid=0 auid=0 ses=2 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:session_close acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'
type=CRED_DISP msg=audit(1483602977.229:259): user pid=9358 uid=0 auid=0 ses=2 subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 msg='op=PAM:setcred acct="root" exe="/usr/bin/sudo" hostname=? addr=? terminal=/dev/pts/0 res=success'
```

> the problem is solved after disabling SeLinux !!! thank you
>   https://serverfault.com/users/200850/koen-van-der-rijt

Comment: can u check the selinux context in /var/lib/mysql? or /var/log/audit/audit.log    for any selinux related problems.

Comment: there is no selinux in /var/lib/mysql, also I have disabled the selinux after reading your comments and still the problem there. please go back to my orginal post above, I have edit it with output of /var/log/audit/audit.log

Comment: the problem is solved, I forget to restart the server after disable the SeLinux. it is working fine now with disabling selinux

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer instead of editing it into the question. It is perfectly acceptable to accept your own answers

Comment: Also note that disabling selinux temporarily for debugging purposes or in a development environment is fine, but you should not disable it in a production environment just because it is an easy solution. Instead, configure selinux correctly for your application. It greatly increases security.

Answer (score -1):

> the problem is solved after disabling SeLinux !!! thank you
>   https://serverfault.com/users/200850/koen-van-der-rijt